# Weird pattern for a laser beam spot

Tags: laser, camera, laser-interaction

I am trying to measure the gaussian profile of a laser beam, which is supposed to be T00. The profile shown in the specifications looks very Gaussian, and the laser is brand new. I am using [this](https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=CS165MU) camera and I am using 2 of [these](https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=PS814) wedges to guide the laser beam into the camera (mainly to reduce the power). However what I am getting is the figure below. The central, bright spot looks basically like what I expect, but on top of that I see some sort of interference fringes. I don't think this is from the laser (I hope not!) as these would be a lot higher order modes than the expected T00, but I am not sure what they can be from. I made sure (as much as I could) that the light hits the camera perpendicularly. Does anyone have any idea what can cause this? Thank you!

Edit: I attached below a picture of my setup.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It'd be useful to see the optical setup you used. These fringes may be due to interference between inter-reflected beams.

Comment: @Ruslan I will take a pic of it and upload it when I am back in the lab. What do you mean by interreflected beams?

Comment: Was this pattern stationary or moving? Like, if the camera raster scanning is slow, you would get such moving bands like in old TVs...

Comment: I mean the wedges are not coated, so there may be stray reflections that affect the final image. But without seeing the optical setup it's hard to diagnose.

Comment: @AlphaLife it is static.

Comment: @Ruslan, isn't the 10 degree angle high enough such that the reflected light from the first surface won't interfere with the reflection from the back surface?

Comment: Again, the figure of 10° only appears in a comment (and references something no one but you has ever seen). There's no info how exactly your optical devices and beams are configured.

Comment: @Ruslan I added a pic of the setup

Comment: Might be due to reflections from the inner side of the black tube. Does the pattern move relative to the peak if you rotate the tube a bit around the vertical screw?

Comment: @Ruslan actually the interference is there even if I remove the tube completely. However the interference pattern changes if I move the beam spot on the camera screen, for example by slightly rotating the middle wedge (which makes me believe it is not from the laser, but I still don't know from what)

Comment: The sensor in the camera seems to be behind a glass window, isn't it? Reflections inside this glass as well as between the sensor and the glass might be the reason for this interference (particularly if the window is not parallel enough to the sensor). Similar to the Newton's rings, but in 1D.

Comment: @Ruslan thanks a lot for this! This makes sense, especially given that I see this interference even without the wedges (e.g. by using a density filter). I just wished they stated that in their product specifications...

Comment: [Drawing and documents](https://www.thorlabs.com/drawings/68ca21dee86afccc-CF8A527D-0EFF-9D75-4A3EAA7AA5343B85/PS814-AutoCADPDF.pdf)